# Which technology do YouTube and Vimeo use for processing 1080 HD Video?

Tags: youtube

For me personally seems youtube videos crisper in 1080 or "original size".

Vimeo seems a little fuzzy when HD is on.

What technology does Youtube use, and why is it apparently better? What is the difference between the two technologies?

Comment: As it stands, the title of your question could be on topic, but the body of the question is definitely off topic.  Please edit the question to better fit the guidelines in the [FAQ](http://avp.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @FriendOfGeorge: I edited the last sentence to conform to the title. Is the question now on topic?

Comment: @TomAu: since this question was closed over 3 years ago,  it is probably best to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are powered by flash, which can read most file types, so I think it really has to do with the way and speed it is buffered.